# array of wchar_t

Tags: c++, unmanaged, visual-c++-2005, wchar-t, wchar

I would like to have an array of wchar_t's.

The following works:

```
char** stringArray;
int maxWords = 3;
stringArray = new char*[maxWords];
stringArray[0] = "I";
stringArray[1] = " Love ";
stringArray[2] = "C++"
```

but this does not

```
wchar_t ** wcAltFinalText;
wcAltFinalText = new wchar_t *[MAX_ALT_SOURCE];   // MAX_ALT_SOURCE = 4
wcAltFinalText[0] = L'\0';
wcAltFinalText[1] = L'\0';
wcAltFinalText[2] = L'\0';
wcAltFinalText[3] = L'\0';
```

I do not get any error but wcAltFinalText is a bad ptr

Any help and comments are much appreciated.

Comment: Why do people insist on doing things the hard way? Why don't they all just use `std::vector<std::wstring>`?

Comment: `wcAltFinalText` is not a bad_ptr (when debugging using VS), `wcAltFinalText[0]` is a bad_ptr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `''` instead of `""`, so the assignment `wcAltFinalText[0] = L'\0';` is equivalent to `wcAltFinalText[0] = 0;`

Answer (score 5):

```
wcAltFinalText[0] = L'\0';
```

`L'\0'` is a wide character literal, this is an integral type - the above line corresponds to

```
wcAltFinalText[0] = 0;
```

What you want is a **string** literal, `L"\0";`

Comment: How is L"\0" an improvement over L""?

Comment: @Bo: It's not - it demonstrates the difference in between char and string literal syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you just set all elements in the newly created array to null pointers (because `L'\0'` is "null character", not an "empty string") - what else would you expect? You have the same effect as with this code:

```
wcAltFinalText[0] = 0;
wcAltFinalText[1] = 0;
wcAltFinalText[2] = 0;
wcAltFinalText[3] = 0;
```

and Visual Studio displays null pointers as "bad ptr" meaning no data can be behind such pointer.

Comment: got it - It  should have been `L"\n";`

Comment: ... expanded to `wchar_t(0)`, which is implicitly converted to `int(0)`, which is implicitly converted to `null_ptr`?

Comment: @xtofl: `int(0)` converted to `(wchar_t*)0` if anything.